# Export Crystal Report 13 to pdf and excel

Tags: vb.net, pdf, crystal-reports, export-to-excel

We are currently running CR 8.5 and giving users the option to export the report to Excel or PDF (Code is done in VB.Net).  In 8.5 we were able to set up one report to run both formats with minimal formatting issues. This allowed the small amount of users selecting excel option to easily manipulate data without any problems.  Switching to CR 13, I am running into an issue where this is no longer the case.  When I run a report that looks ok for pdf, it does not set up well for data manipulation in excel.  I have done extensive research in designing reports from excel, but this, of course, truncates a lot of data in pdf version.  I have set the ExportFormatType in code to use both Excel and ExcelRecord (which works ok if report doesn't use grouping or sub totals). I realize CR and Excel don't work well together, but is there any way find a happy medium here?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do the same thing you do and unfortunately what I've done is have two versions, one formatted for the "pixel perfect" print (PDF) and one for Excel.  I also have had terrible experiences with Crystal exporting to "Excel" so I almost always use the "ExcelRecord" or Data Only that spits it out with no formatting.

Comment: I was able to set the report up to where excel's Unmerge Cells works without killing my formatting.  Row wise, I set the report up for excel, so all cell heights are the same, also added spacers where needed so things didn't float on me.  I set the column widths up to show whole field in pdf and let the unmerge function handle the rest.